# Why is mktemp -u considered "unsafe"?

Tags: files, filenames, gnu, coreutils, mktemp

I read the `--help` text for `mktemp` recently (the `man` page wasn't available) and came upon this:

```
  -u, --dry-run       do not create anything; merely print a name (unsafe)
```

Why is this "unsafe"? Is there any specific reason for this being marked as such?

Comment: I don't "feel" like `mktemp` without `-u` is particularly safe, either, at least when creating temp files, not dirs. The temp file could've been accidentally deleted since it was created until it was first used, and then we're back where we started from -- opportunity for symlink attack. If you're using any shell with here-strings (bash, ksh, zsh) on Linux, this will create a temp file with two separate handles  (7 for read, 8 for write) to it, which will be completely managed by the shell (you don't have to remove it or care about its path, etc): `exec 7<<<'' 8>/dev/fd/7`.

Comment: Unfortunately, that trick no longer works in `bash-5.0`. Apparently, it's the effect of a fix for [this bug](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/bug-bash/2018-03/msg00064.html). Sad.

Comment: But then, bash is (and was) just re-opening the temp file _by its name_, which is just as damn racy as any kludge put together with `mktemp(1)` and `rm`.

Comment: For completion, here is an example of bash not being able to use a here-doc because the tempfile was "accidentally" deleted (the `head -n 6000` may have to be adjusted): `while ! rm /tmp/sh-thd* 2>/dev/null; do : ; done & (printf "cat <<foo >/dev/null\n"; yes line | head -n6000; printf "foo") | bash; kill $!`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole point of `mktemp` is, to quote its manual, to “create  a  temporary  file or directory, safely”. Basically, in a script, you can write

```
file="$(mktemp)"
```

or

```
dir="$(mktemp -d)"
```

and use either as you wish, safe in the knowledge that the temporary file and directory are accessible only by the user running the command (and root, of course, in most setups), and that they aren’t a symlink to something else, etc. (There are still some caveats; in particular, you need to check the exit status, and the parent directory needs to be safe to use. See [the documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/mktemp-invocation.html) for details.)

`mktemp -u` doesn’t give these guarantees, because it separates the construction of the file name from its use; in a script, you’d have to run (**don’t do this**)

```
dir="$(mktemp -u)"
mkdir "$dir"
chmod 700 "$dir"
```

In between `mktemp` and `mkdir`, another process can create the directory, with different ownership; or, in the case of a file, another process can create the file or create a symlink in its place...

Comment: If they can create the file, can't they just remove the file created by `mktemp` and then recreate it using different permissions? What safety is `mktemp` adding?

Comment: @HappyFace if the parent directory is safe to use, *e.g.* a correctly set-up `/tmp` with the sticky bit set, only the owning user and root can delete a file or directory. `mktemp` gives you a file or directory with an unpredictable name which you own and are sure was created just for you (otherwise `mktemp` would indicate an error).