# How can I get exit status of subshell?

Tags: exit-status, subshell

A classical example of **piping**:

```
$ false | true
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
1 0
```

Same example **run in a subshell** and assigning results into a variable:

```
$ process="$(false | true)"
$ echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]}
0
```

How could I get the **exit status** of each of the piped processes?

[Similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14270/get-exit-status-of-process-thats-piped-to-another), without the subshell part:

Comment: `process="$(false | true ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} >&2)"` or `process="$(false | true ; echo ${PIPESTATUS[@]} >/dev/tty)"`

Comment: well, you do the `echo ${PIPESTATUS}` _inside_ the command substitution subshell ;-) I guess your question is more about how to capture output other than stdout from a command substitution.

Comment: ... which is "interesting", since there are no nice solutions, only ugly kludges. For instance, this will use a tempfile to get the data out, while leaving stdout and stderr undisturbed: `t=$(mktemp); exec 3>$t 4<$t; rm "$t"; out=$(false | true | false | echo hmm; echo -n "${PIPESTATUS[@]}" >&3); readarray -td' ' st <&4; exec 3>&- 4<&-; echo "out=$out; st=(${st[*]})"`. Related: [Redirect STDERR and STDOUT to different variables without temporary files](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430161/redirect-stderr-and-stdout-to-different-variables-without-temporary-files)

Comment: btw, you got you quoting backwards: you should quote the `${PIPESTATUS[@]}` in `echo "${PIPESTATUS[@]}"`, but you don't have to quote the `$(...)` in `process=$(false | true)`.